# Error plug-in: "org.eclipse.text" in eclipse 4.3

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a error in eclipse as follows:

```
!SESSION 2014-11-27 08:59:05.330 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

This is a continuation of log file /home/dragonk/workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-11-27 10:19:19.795

!ENTRY org.eclipse.text 4 2 2014-11-27 10:19:19.796
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.text".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed:
```

It make me out of control editor in eclipse.
Please hepl me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Its a compatibility issue. Please refer to this official guide of Eclipse. 
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.3.php